# Mediawrapper not removed from the content added though ckeditor from Media module?

Tags: wysiwyg, media

I have added image/video into ckeditor using Media module.There is a media wrapper tag around img tag when i click the source.But when i save it and view it in the node the output is as below

```
    <div class="field-item even">
       <p>
          <mediawrapper data=""><br>
             <picture class="media-element file-article-page" data-fid="254" data-media-element="1">
              </picture></mediawrapper>
       </p>
<!--[if IE 9]>
       <video style="display: none;"><![endif]-->
       <p>
    <source media="only screen and (min-width: 1300px)" srcset="http://mdm.dev.local/sites/default/files/styles/story_main_imgbreakpoints_theme_mdm_theme_wide_1x/public/Satwinder-Singh-Bh.jpg?itok=Xa2QkiIM 1x"></p>

<p>&nbsp;</p>

<p><source media="(min-width: 980px)" srcset="http://mdm.dev.local/sites/default/files/styles/story_main_imgbreakpoints_theme_mdm_theme_normal_1x/public/Satwinder-Singh-Bh.jpg?itok=4-_MEyLT 1x"><source media="(min-width: 740px)" srcset="http://mdm.dev.local/sites/default/files/styles/story_main_imgbreakpoints_theme_mdm_theme_narrow_1x/public/Satwinder-Singh-Bh.jpg?itok=Ix6a8-i4 1x">

<source media="(min-width: 320px)" srcset="http://mdm.dev.local/sites/default/files/styles/story_main_imgbreakpoints_theme_mdm_theme_mobile_1x/public/Satwinder-Singh-Bh.jpg?itok=GawXXe4L 1x"></p>
<p><!--[if IE 9]></video>

<![endif]--><!--[if lt IE 9]><p><img typeof="foaf:Image" src="http://mdm.dev.local/sites/default/files/styles/story_main_imgbreakpoints_theme_mdm_theme_mobile_1x/public/Satwinder-Singh-Bh.jpg?itok=GawXXe4L" alt="" title="" /><br />
<![endif]--></p>
<!--[if !lt IE 9]><!--><p>

<img alt="" height="170" src="null" srcset="http://mdm.dev.local/sites/default/files/styles/story_main_imgbreakpoints_theme_mdm_theme_mobile_1x/public/Satwinder-Singh-Bh.jpg?itok=GawXXe4L 200w" title="" width="253">
```

Image has picture tag but it is seperated and only the image with img tag is shown instead of all picture element together.Also the Media wrapper are not converted.I have enabled "Convert Media tags to markup" in text formats.What else do i need to get the picture tag work along with media module?

Comment: Is the source provided here what you see in the editor or what you see on the page load?

Comment: It is what i seen on the page load..seems like picture tag is not recognized..

Comment: Looks like bug in Picture module…